# Upgrade/migrate a Microsoft Cluster

Tags: clustering

We currently have active/active windows 2008 cluster hosting 2 instances of SQL 2008 R2. We have a new hardware for windows 2012 clustering. We want to use this new hardware to upgrade the active/active win 2008 cluster to win 2012 cluster. Is there an upgrade path without changing the 2 SQL instance names? We can't upgrade the SQL instance to SQL 2012 though. Is it better to stand up the new cluster 2012 by shutting down the old cluster, removing from AD and use the old cluster virtual name or is it better to stand up a brand new cluster 2012 and install SQL 2008 R2 and migrate the databases. Which one is the best practice or best way of doing it? Appreciate your advise on this. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to maintain the virtual instance names then you don't have any choice other than building it as you've described